# MongoDB updateOne method updates document that does not match filter

Tags: mongodb

updateOne() is updating a document that does not match the filter...

sampe data in db.test:

```
[
{name: "Fred", age:30},
{name: "Barney", age:25}
]
```

I run the following on it:

```
data = {name: "Fred", age: 40}
db.test.updateOne({x:"x"}, {$set:data})
```

result:

```
[
{name: "Fred", age:40},
{name: "Barney", age:25}
]
```

???

Comment: Your query is working "normal" in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fKtuw_qwuXz). Please check whether there is some config/environment issue, e.g. querying incorrect DB/collection

Answer (score 0):

Change like this 
 `db.test.updateOne({name:"Fred"}, {$set:data})`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).